# Function lock and Mutex usage behaving differently in IIS Express and IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iis, wkhtmltopdf

In my web application I use `wkhtmltopdf` to process reports to output them as a PDF. I have a few functions that compile some HTML together, some headers etc. and then pass this information to `wkhtmltopdf` to compile the PDF and serve it to the user.

Something like:

```
public JsonResult BuildPDF(string one, string two, SomeData[] data, SomeList[] {
 lock(PDFLock) {
      // ... Code here to compile HTML and save to files

      ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
      psi.FileName = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
      psi.UseShellExecute = true;
      psi.Verb = "runas";
      ...
      Process p = Process.Start(psi);
      p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

After the PDF is compiled I push it to the user then delete the file.

As you can see I have a lock around this function to prevent two attempts at processing a PDF at one time. **On `IIS Express` this function behaves as I would expect: if two requests are made at the exact same time, the request that makes it in first will be processed, and the 2nd request will sit and wait on the lock until the first request is complete.**

**In release IIS, it appears to be ignoring this lock,** and does not wait for the first request to be finished. It actually ends up skipping through the function so quickly that the first request is *still running* while the 2nd request completes (unsuccessfully), so the user receives a message that the request failed.

I am unsure why it would ignore this lock, or why it would work in debug (IIS Express).

Is there any possibility this is due to IIS's configuration?

Edit:

The issue with `lock` was a problem of multiple worker processes in IIS. I am testing Mutex again now with multiple processes.

Edit:

Mutex usage: the Mutex is declared in the class as `private static Mutex mut = new Mutex();`

```
public JsonResult BuildPDF(string one, string two, SomeData[] data, SomeList[] {
      mut.WaitOne();
      // ... Code here to compile HTML and save to files

      ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
      psi.FileName = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
      psi.UseShellExecute = true;
      psi.Verb = "runas";
      ...
      Process p = Process.Start(psi);
      p.WaitForExit();

     //... Return some JSON to user
    }
```

Then inside the `Download` method:

```
public virtual void Download() {
 // ... Response headers and stuff
    Response.TransmitFile(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\temppdfs\pdfout.pdf");
    Response.End();                      

   System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\temppdfs\pdfout.pdf");
    mut.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that `Process.Start` won't block the current thread (i.e execution will continue after the process is started). If that is true your lock will be released whilst your process is still running.

Comment: Hmm maybe that is the case, but I am unsure why it works correctly in IIS Express then :S

Comment: I should also note that I have `p.WaitForExit();`, which I had hoped would block until the process has exited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding was a bit off on `lock` and `Mutex` usage.

The reason `lock` was not working is my application pool in IIS had multiple worker processes allowed (4), so the lock could not work cross-process.

I was using the `Mutex`  improperly by declaring it outside the functions, now the proper usage of `Mutex` in my case (release IIS with multiple processes in the application pool):

```
public JsonResult BuildPDF(string one, string two, SomeData[] data, SomeList[] {
   Mutex mut = new Mutex(false, @"Global\PDFMutex");
   mut.WaitOne();

  // ... Code here to compile HTML and save to files

  ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
  psi.FileName = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
  psi.UseShellExecute = true;
  psi.Verb = "runas";
  ...
  Process p = Process.Start(psi);
  p.WaitForExit();

  mut.ReleaseMutex();

 //... Return some JSON to user
}
```

This usage of `Mutex` appears to be successful across multiple processes and multiple functions.